# PHP Login System Any password works

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a login system as practice and I ran into a problem I just can't seem to get by. Below is all my code.

See I set my password as the long code you get if you type in ***echo "$password";*** below line 43 ***$password = md5(md5("j3d4k",$password));***. Then on the browser it gives you that code so I put that code in the password on my database as the tutorial I watched said. Now it allows me to login as my user with any password. So I decided to set the password back as password1 for a minute to see if I could log in with that password and if it wouldn't let me if I entered the wrong password. Still failed. It now won't let me enter any password says they are all incorrect.

### login.php

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Login</title>

<style>

</style>

</head>
<body>
<?php 

    $form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td><td><input type='text' name='user' placeholder='Username' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login' /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>";

    if ($_POST['loginbtn']){
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if ($user){
            if ($password){
                require("connect.php");

                $password = md5(md5("j3d4k",$password));                
                // make sure login info correct                         
                $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
                $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                if ($numrows == 1){
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                    $dbid = $row['id'];
                    $dbuser = $row['username'];
                    $dbpass = $row['password'];
                    $dbactive = $row['active'];

                    if ($password == $dbpass){
                        if ($dbactive == 1){

                            // set session info
                            $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;

                            echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b>. <a href='./member.php'>Click here</a> to go to the member page";

                        }
                        else
                            echo "You must activate your account to login. $form";
                    }
                    else
                        echo "You did not enter the correct password. $form";
                }
                else
                    echo "The username you entered was not found. $form";

                mysqli_close($con);
            }
            else
                echo "You must enter your password. $form";
        }
        else
            echo "You must enter your username. $form";
    }
    else
        echo $form;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

### connect.php

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Joshua", "Danielle104");
mysqli_select_db($con, "user");

?>
```

Comment: Just a tip: separate your logic from presentation, it'll be so much easier to manage.

Comment: like this $password = password_hash(md5("j3d4k",$password));

Comment: @Fred-ii- password_hash() requires php 5.5+. Unfortunately, many hosts don't have php 5.5 installed on their systems. He can use PHP's hash function with sha256 for example for more secure hashing.

Comment: @Joshua nope, like this `$password = password_hash($password);`

Comment: The best way to have a login system, is not to do it your self. Why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoMOAIzBSpY

Comment: @castis I got this error message after that. Warning: password_hash() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\WAMP\www\tutorial\login.php on line 43

Comment: @Joshua my apologies, it should be `$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I agree, sha is not the best, and not even close to it. Personally I use PHP's password_hash(), just because I also setup the servers for the applications that I develop, and I'm sure PHP 5.5 is on them

Comment: and don't forget the `password_verify()`.

Comment: @castis Hey thanks very much it did work. However I still have a problem something must be wrong with my code because it still says You did not enter the correct password I just can't seem to spot the problem.

Comment: Did you check out Ishamael's answer below? Was that your problem?

Comment: @Mike There was a lot of problems. I have a bad mentor called youtube where videos are 1000 years old so things are outdated or missused I'm going to restart this is just practice so it doesn't matter my goals just to learn what I need to know for building a basic browser textbased mmorpg game. Than I'll just keep upgrading as I learn. :)

Comment: @diggersworld What do you mean?

Comment: Text-based MMORPG? Sounds like a pretty big project just for learning with, but hey, you gotta start somewhere. I can't vouch for the 1000 year old Youtube videos, but I would really recommend http://www.phptherightway.com/. It's worth taking the time to go through it, especially the parts on databases and security. I would tend to think that MMORPGs (if they become popular) frequent targets for hackers trying to cheat, and/or wipe your whole database out by exploiting the SQL injection error you have in the code above. Here's another good resource: http://wiki.hashphp.org/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using [hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function.

For example, set the value of hash("sha256", "j3d4k") in your database password column. The result will be "0dd15cf0c18375808efdbb7f7180526a6355fe02db72365d1ea0c70165e868d0".

Then when you check, use the same hash on the user input, and than compare vs the stored password.

```
$password = hash("sha256", $_POST['password']);
```

UPDATE:
By the way - your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. **Never** use user input directly inside of a query.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your question is actually exactly as expected (you should not be able to connect using password `password1` in your second scenario, because your entry in the database "password1" doesn't match the **hash** of the password entered in the form).

The only thing that seems to be suspicious is that when you set the `password` in the database to the hash you printed, you can log in with **any** password. This clearly is not the expected behavior.

My guess would be that you actually define a global variable called `$password` in your `connect.php`, probably with your database password. This way by the line `43` the value of the `$password` will always be the same, no matter what password you entered in the form, and thus the hash will also be the same. To confirm it, print the value of `$password` right after you `require('connect.php')`, and see if that's the password you entered into the form.

Comment: I've seen that happen quite a few times before, where people would use the `$password` variable for DB connection/variable from a form. Yep, seen it all too often.